# Will my laptop be ok with this different laptop charger?

Tags: laptop, charger, voltage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Charging laptop with non-original charger](https://superuser.com/questions/32372/charging-laptop-with-non-original-charger)
>   [How can I tell if an AC adapter is compatible with my laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/53645/how-can-i-tell-if-an-ac-adapter-is-compatible-with-my-laptop)

So the original laptop charger broke and I switched to a charger from a laptop that I no longer use.
The specifications from each are:

**Original**
Input:AC 100-240V 1.5A 50-60Hz
Output: DC 19V 3.42A

**Other Charger**
Input: AC 100-240V 1.5A 50-60Hz
Output: 20V 3.25A

Yes, the polarity is the same.

Also, the wattage has a difference of .02 from what I understand. Is wattage ever important, and more specifically, a wattage difference of that size.

Feel free to ask me any other questions about the chargers and I'll answer them to the best of my ability.

Comment: Do none of the following and many, *many* more besides help? [Charging laptop with non-original charger](http://superuser.com/questions/32372/charging-laptop-with-non-original-charger), [Can a laptop run on a different brand charger?](http://superuser.com/questions/352573/can-a-laptop-run-on-a-different-brand-charger), [charging laptop with a different adapter charger](http://superuser.com/questions/362581/charging-laptop-with-a-different-adapter-charger)

Comment: [Is it possible to use a laptop charger in other laptop with different specifications?](http://superuser.com/questions/486642/is-it-possible-to-use-a-laptop-charger-in-other-laptop-with-different-specificat), [Using a higher current charger on a laptop which requires a lower current](http://superuser.com/questions/318522/using-a-higher-current-charger-on-a-laptop-which-requires-a-lower-current), [Can I use a charger with less Ampere than the original?](http://superuser.com/questions/425250/can-i-use-a-charger-with-less-ampere-than-the-original)

Comment: [HP charger with Dell Laptop](http://superuser.com/questions/393076/hp-charger-with-dell-laptop), [Charger has fuse busted, could I use this other charger?](http://superuser.com/questions/426013/charger-has-fuse-busted-could-i-use-this-other-charger-details-inside), [Can a 20V 4.51A power supply be used with a computer that requires a 19V 3.42A power supply?](http://superuser.com/questions/245715/can-a-20v-4-51a-power-supply-be-used-with-a-computer-that-requires-a-19v-3-42a-p) ...

Answer (score 0):

You're very close to the 5% tolerances power supplies are designed to. You may be asking the power supply for a little bit more power than it was designed to supply. Make sure it's not getting unusually hot.

Comment: It's not *well* within 5% - it's *almost* within 5%. The voltage is just over 5% more (5.26%). I don't know how much higher a voltage is typically safe, but a voltage too high (at some level) would blow components. (A voltage too *low* would be unlikely to cause to damage (it could get a low voltage from a dead battery and would have to tolerate it), but might not work, and a *higher current* should work (but see Selali Adobor's answer in https://superuser.com/questions/393076/hp-charger-with-dell-laptop?noredirect=1&lq=1)). The current is almost 5% lower, but that's unlikely to be a problem.